# Nginx doesn't work as expected (shows default page)(Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

Can't figure out where is the problem with my configuration. I have DigitalOcean VPS where I run Django project. 
I've configured Gunicorn and Nginx. 
Set correct IP address. 
Checked gunicorn status (ok).

No errors in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

NGinx is still showing the default page instead of Django project homepage.

Even deleted `default` from `sites-enabled` and still see `nginx` default page.

**gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=django
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/django/nameofmyproject
ExecStart=/home/django/nameofmyproject/nameofmyprojectvenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/django/nameofmyproject/nameofmyproject.sock nameofmyproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**sites-available/nameofmyproject**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <my_ip_address>;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/django/nameofmyproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/django/nameofmyproject/nameofmyproject.sock;
    }
}
```

**gunicorn status**

```
unicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-10-19 09:56:18 UTC; 1min 2s ago
 Main PID: 1372 (gunicorn)
    Tasks: 4
   Memory: 138.0M
      CPU: 3.971s
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
           ├─1372 /home/django/nameofmyproject/nameofmyprojectvenv/bin/python /home/django/nameofmyproject/nameofmyprojectvenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --work
           ├─1555 /home/django/nameofmyproject/nameofmyprojectvenv/bin/python /home/django/nameofmyproject/nameofmyprojectvenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --work
           ├─1556 /home/django/nameofmyproject/nameofmyprojectvenv/bin/python /home/django/nameofmyproject/nameofmyprojectvenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --work
           └─1557 /home/django/nameofmyproject/nameofmyprojectvenv/bin/python /home/django/nameofmyproject/nameofmyprojectvenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --work

Oct 19 09:56:18 ubuntu-16 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Oct 19 09:56:21 ubuntu-16 gunicorn[1372]: [2017-10-19 09:56:21 +0000] [1372] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
Oct 19 09:56:21 ubuntu-16 gunicorn[1372]: [2017-10-19 09:56:21 +0000] [1372] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/django/nameofmyproject/nameofmyproject
Oct 19 09:56:21 ubuntu-16 gunicorn[1372]: [2017-10-19 09:56:21 +0000] [1372] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Oct 19 09:56:21 ubuntu-16 gunicorn[1372]: [2017-10-19 09:56:21 +0000] [1555] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1555
Oct 19 09:56:21 ubuntu-16 gunicorn[1372]: [2017-10-19 09:56:21 +0000] [1556] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1556
Oct 19 09:56:22 ubuntu-16 gunicorn[1372]: [2017-10-19 09:56:21 +0000] [1557] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1557
```

Really don't know where is the problem. How to debug this?

Comment: Change `listen 80;` to `listen 80 default_server;` and see if it fixes the issue

Answer (score 1):

Make sure You did the following

1. create a symbolic link of your nginx conf in **sites-available** to **sites-enabled**.
2. Reload nginx after deleting **default** conf

Comment: No it didn't help. I had already symlink but tried to make it again and reload nginx.

Comment: Then try with another listen port like 8000. Make sure 8000 port of you server is open.
listen 8000;

Comment: That's weird. I've changed port to 8000 and did: sudo nginx -s reload
sudo systemctl restart nginx But it say "This site can't be reached" when I go to <myip>:8000. <myip> still works

Comment: Is port 8000 open in you server

Comment: Yes it was. I've decided to create a new vps after hours of debugging and it works. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik What was the issue then??